# Upper bounds for the Artin-Rees Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

The Artin-Rees Lemma says that for an ideal $I$ in a Noetherian ring $R$, and for finitely generated $R$-modules $N \subseteq M$, there exists a positive integer $k$ such that for all $n \geq k$, it holds that $I^nM \cap N = I^{n-k}(I^kM \cap N)$.

In [this mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184414/uniform-artin-rees), the question arises whether there is a nice upper bound, maybe related to the Krull dimension of $R$, for $k$.

I would be also interested in this. So, I ask again here: Can one give an upper bound for $k$?

Could this be easier in the case when $M = R$ and so $N$ is an ideal of $R$? Or, even more specifically, if $R$ is a polynomial ring over a field?

Thank you in advance!